# ToolBar not shown when done programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios

I removed the ToolBar control from IB but instead tried to create thru code. I tried the following code that I found online. Instead of writing this code in "viewWillAppear", I have my code in a "bar button item" in the navigation bar on the same UIViewController.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

//Initialize the toolbar
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

//Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app.
[toolbar sizeToFit];

//Caclulate the height of the toolbar
CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

//Get the bounds of the parent view
CGRect rootViewBounds = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;

//Get the height of the parent view.
CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);

//Get the width of the parent view,
CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

//Create a rectangle for the toolbar
CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth,  toolbarHeight);

//Reposition and resize the receiver
[toolbar setFrame:rectArea];

//Create a button
UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];

//Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
//[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

// Instead of adding to a navigation controller (which I don't have), I'm adding directly to the view and is not shown at all.

// Hiding the tabBar before I show the toolbar    
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

[self.view addSubview: self.toolbar];
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Do I have to have the info_clicked method available (bar button item click)?

Comment: Maybe this is my ignorance about IOS showing, but isn't the default initializer for any view subclasses `-initWithFrame:`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me....

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
 toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,44);
 UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)];
 [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];
 [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
    [toolBar release];
```

You also need the method info_clicked: to receive the button action.

```
- (IBAction)info_clicked:(id)sender{
   NSLog("clicked info_button");
}
```

Comment: Let me tell you my issue: I'm using the UITabBar application template and I extended the app by adding a navigation bar with a bar button item on the top and a toolbar at the bottom in the first view controller. All I need is on the click of the button, hide the tabbar and show the toolbar. I have created the toolbar thru IB. What is happening is the tabbar hides and toolbar shows but there is a big space where the tabbar was visible. I wanted to move the toolbar to the bottom of the view where the tabbar was displayed previously. I'm surprised why it is so difficult to achieve. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"SHOW BAR" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showToolbar:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem;


    self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
    self.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 325, self.view.frame.size.width,44);
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)];
    [self.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];
    [self.toolbar setHidden:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (IBAction)showToolbar:(id)sender{
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
    [self.toolbar setHidden:NO];
  }
```

Of course this code will only work on the iPhone in portrait mode. You would have to change the numbers around for landscape or iPad...And look out for interface orientation changes.

Comment: Thank you. Please see the image: http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/421/screenshot20120103at114.png. You will observe from the image that the toolbar is hiding behind the tabbar. If I hide the tabbar, the toolbar is shown above and there is a big space (where the tabbar was visible). I need to move the toolbar to the exact location of the tabbar. I need to modify the label (shown with 1) after the toolbar is shown properly. Just wanted to let you know that the tabbar is created dynamically from code (Tabbar app template) in the appdelegate.m. I modified your code to move by 400 instead of 325.

Answer (score 0):

hi friend this code may help you too...

```
 UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 960, self.view.frame.size.width,44);
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)];
   // [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[toolbar setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[toolbar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:toolbar];
[self.tabBarController.view bringSubviewToFront:toolbar];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

actually tabbar is one of view controller so you can add the toolbar in tabbar itself, solves your previous problem.Have a great Day!!!.

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely give a try. But, how about this? Can I use IB to add the toolbar and bar button items and then in the navigation bar button click, add specific code from your snippet to assign the toolbar as a subview to tabbarcontroller? Will that work or I have to do everything from code? Btw, did you take a look at the picture I linked earlier?

Comment: I already seen your screen shot. I created the tab bar application and then add the tool bar programmatically I am also face same problem when I am add toolbar as subview in self.view it is behind the tabbar(like your screen shot) after I analyse the tabbar  is subview of tabbar view controller using this code added the toolbar in it.[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:toolbar]  it works fine for me best wishes!!! for your success