# Toolbar disappears when hiding keyboard

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a nav controller with a toolbar. I made the toolbar also appear on top of the keyboard when the keyboard appears. When I dismiss the keyboard, the toolbar disappears, leaving a black rectangle at the bottom of the screen, just where the toolbar should be without the keyboard.

Here's how I init the toolbar:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

    // this makes sure the toolbar appears on top of the keyboard
    // instead of going below it.
    // _nameText is a UITextField
    _nameText.inputAccessoryView = self.navigationController.toolbar;
}
```

This is how I hide the keyboard:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]; // this doesn't help
    return NO;
}
```

I tried also doing `[self.view setNeedsLayout]`, but that didn't work.

EDIT: I suspect this may have to do with the fact that I assign the toolbar to be the input accessory view of my text field. I think that the text field hides its accessory view when the keyboard goes away. I still don't know how to override that behavior though.

EDIT 2: I discovered that `self.navigationController.toolbar.superview` is `nil` after the keyboard is gone.

Comment: Try adding `self.navigationController.toolbar` to the view(without keyboard) again.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. The toolbar: (1) appears on the top of the screen, and (2) disappears again in a split second. I tried `[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.toolbar]`.

Comment: It looks like you've moved the toolbar out of visibility. Pls post your code for moving the toolbar above the virtual keyboard and when you hide the keyboard. You can try `NSLog`ging the frame of the toolbar after the keyboard is hidden

Comment: This line: `_nameText.inputAccessoryView = self.navigationController.toolbar;` is the only thing I had to do for the toolbar to appear above the keyboard. I don't do anything special when hiding the keyboard, just `[textField resignFirstResponder]`.

Comment: if `self.navigationController.toolbar.superview` came out as `nil`, then I presume you've solved the problem

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't. It only becomes nil if I set my toolbar as the input accessory view. If I don't do that, the toolbar stays on screen always (but gets under the keyboard when the keyboard is shown). I think that the toolbar may be getting "orphaned" somewhere in the process, if that makes sense. And like I said before, adding the toolbar to `self.view` doesn't work.

Comment: You might be right about the "orphaned" theory! If you want to continue this way, then you can `alloc` and [add a toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721996/toolbar-not-shown-when-done-programatically) again. If you can make a little change(I'd prefer this way), then just set the frame of the toolbar when the keyboard is presented/hidden instead of what you're doing right now.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to do something similar to what you propose. Namely I'll make sure that the toolbar that goes above the keyboard is a different toolbar from the one provided by UINavigationController. I'll just create a .xib for the "above the keyboard" toolbar and load it from there. Not the most elegant solution, but I'll take whatever I can get at this point :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so while I couldn't solve the problem head-on, I found an acceptable workaround.

1. Create a .xib for your toolbar
2. Load the toolbar from (1) into an object
3. assign that object to the `inputAccessoryView` property of your text field
4. set up the target and the actions for the buttons in this toolbar, so you can respond to clicks

You are now all set. Your original toolbar (which you presumably have created in the Interface Builder) is only visible when the keyboard is hidden. When the keyboard is visible, the original toolbar cannot be seen, but your other one (created with the steps described above) now appears above the keyboard. Bingo!

If anyone has a more elegant solution to this problem, I'd be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: It's matter when thing need sync between these two toolBar.

Answer (score 1):

@BlackRider, I ran into the same exact issue as you.  It is quite annoying.

I didn't want to set up 2 different toolbars as a workaround, as I didn't want to handle the state of the toolbar buttons in 2 different places.

I've resorted to using the approach discussed here in the answer that uses notifications: [iPhone: How to fix inputAccessoryView to View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784171/iphone-how-to-fix-inputaccessoryview-to-view)

It's working ok - my gut reaction is that I'll run into issues when trying on various device sizes / orientations.